# How to fix getting None value on serializing ManyToManyField in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework, many-to-many

Sorry to ask a repetitive question which is already have been asked a lot of times. I have seen alot of answers on this topic. But I can't reproduce the solution of my problem.
Basically I want to serialize a field name partner which is in quote model

```
class Quote(models.Model):
     #...
     partner = models.ManyToManyField(
        Partner, blank=True, related_name='quote_partners')
```

and this is the Partner models in the accounts app

```
class Partner(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True,
                          unique=True,
                          default=uuid.uuid4,
                          editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    group = models.OneToOneField(
        Group, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

And this is how the serializer looks

```
class QuoteListSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    """ For the List views """
    #...
    id = serializers.UUIDField(read_only=True)
    partner = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)
```

I'm getting all other fields properly but not the partner field.
This is the end results looks like :

```
{           
            "id": "cbf64980-1637-4d0d-ad1f-4eb6421df5a1",
            "partner": "accounts.Partner.None", 
        },
```

However I can see the partners field is filled for this specific entry in the admin page but not showing in the serialized data.
**In the Partner Model**

[image]

**In the Quote**

[[image]][2

Anybody knows why this is happening and how to fix this issue.

Comment: Can you please share your expected response schema?

Comment: uuid of the selected partner in as a `set of partner = [ ]`

Answer (score 1):

If you already have the individual objects of the related fields, and as you mentioned in the comments you want the UUID which is a primary key of the Partner model as well, So can use the `PrimaryKeyRelatedField`.

> PrimaryKeyRelatedField may be used to represent the target of the
> relationship using its primary key. [More Info](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield)

Modify your `QuoteListSerializer`
from

```
partner = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)
```

to

```
partner = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True, many=True)
```

This will return the set of UUID of those specific objects that are linked to your `Quote` model.

```
"partner": [
                "115f1fa8-1cb2-4d49-962d-8c25e8b40240" # UUID of the linked partner
            ],
```

If you want to return the string value then u should use `StringRelatedField`

> StringRelatedField may be used to represent the target of the
> relationship using its `__str__` method. [More Info](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#stringrelatedfield),

This will return the `name` of the Partner Objects as you have set this in the Partner model to `return self.name`

So you can obtain as the following formate,

```
"partner": [
                "Company A" # name of the linked partner
            ],
```

Comment: Thanks , That helped me a lot to understand the problem and that worked.

Answer (score -2):

You have to make also a serializer class of the Partner class. In the QuoteListSerializer you call this partner serializer.The partner serializer will then be nested in the json.

```
class QuoteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    partner = PartnerSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Quote
        fields = __All__ you can exclude fields
```

Comment: I dont want to nest all Partner model instead of linked with many to many relationships with quote

Comment: yes, thats happening if you make a partner serializer class, it will then only show the linked ones. See my edited answer